# ON UPDATE Rule For jsonb

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

In a PostgreSQL 9.5.1 database I have a table:

`CREATE TABLE test.table01 (
    pgid serial NOT NULL,
    sample_id text NOT NULL,
    all_data jsonb NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT table01_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY (pgid)
)`

And a view of that table:

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW test.test_view AS 
    SELECT table01.sample_id,
        table01.all_data ->> 'technician'::text AS technician,
        table01.all_data ->> 'depth'::text AS depth,
        table01.all_data ->> 'colour'::text AS colour,
        table01.all_data ->> 'duplicate of'::text AS dupe_of
    FROM test.table01;`

Finally, on that view, I have created a RULE that aims to correctly modify the underlying jsonb object on updates against the view:

`CREATE OR REPLACE RULE upd_test_view AS
    ON UPDATE TO test.test_view WHERE new.colour <> old.colour
    DO INSTEAD
        UPDATE test.table01 SET all_data = jsonb_set(table01.all_data, '{colour}'::text[], (('"'::text || new.colour) || '"'::text)::jsonb);`

When I subsequently issue

`UPDATE test.test_view SET colour = 'Purple' WHERE sample_id = '1234567';`

I get back

`ERROR:  no relation entry for relid 2
********** Error **********
ERROR: no relation entry for relid 2
SQL state: XX000`

I must be doing something wrong, but I can't quite get my head around it.  Your expertise is very much appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the json functions but your problem might just be that the `sample_id` field isn't defined as a unique key in the original table. Can you use `pgid` instead? Or, if the `sample_id` is unique, add the key for it.

Comment: Don't you need a `WHERE` somewhere in your `UPDATE test.table01 SET all_data = jsonb_set(table01.all_data, '{colour}'::text[], (('"'::text || new.colour) || '"'::text)::jsonb);` ?

Comment: Gulp, yes, definitely.

Comment: Paired with a resolution to my idiocy, that is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in this at all, but I ran into the same error message, and in my case I could solve this by removing the WHERE part of the rule. This will make the rule trigger more frequently, but it solved this problem for me. See if it works for you as well if this is still relevant.